# dotnet core IIS website restart on error (for example sql server reboot)

Tags: iis, .net-core

I'm currently facing the following problem when hosting a dotnet core application with IIS.

When the webserver boots before the database server, the dotnet-application throws an error that it is unable to connect to the database. So for so good offcourse.

But the problem is that when it faces this error on startup, it will never again try to connect to the database. The dotnet core application seems to be giving up when facing a startup error.

Is there some general re-try mechanism available to handle these kind of errors? So for example when the application detects a problem, to restart every 5 minutes?

Comment: It's *your* code that tries to connect to the database, not .NET Core. Even if you use boilerplate code found in some template, it's still your code. Where does the  error occur? Post the relevant code. Perhaps all you need to do is to add an exception handler and redirect to an error page, or simply return an empty array to your controller. Perhaps an exception handler in the controller itself will be enough. If you load configuration settings from the database you'll need something more advanced

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found the answer myself. It was during my startup-logic that I already was connecting to the sql database. I could simply force IIS to try to restart the process, until initialization worked out by explicitly shutting down the application using Environment.Exit(-1); whenever an error occured

Comment: Why not *handle* the exception instead and avoid restarting?

Comment: So the exception is that the database is not operational (for example has not yet started, in case of a global power-failure)

Comment: Post the *code* not a description of exception. Handling it means modifying your code so that it *doesn't* crash the application and retries instead. There's no `global` failure. Just an exception thrown by your `Startup()` method.

Comment: Besides, you *don't* need a database connection to display a view. You only need it when you load data. You don't need to open any connection at startup, unless you want to load configuration data.